# Cannot Start Windows Phone Emulator After Update 1 on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, emulation

I updated VS 2013 with update 1, now have a problem...
When I want to debug a phone appplication on the emulator (including new test projects),  the VS toolbar doesn't show the buttons to deploy to the device or debug on emulator. When  I select debug from drop-down menu the app eventually notifies  me  with:EXCEPTION RESULT 0x80131500

Also a dialog about Hyper-V not enabled  (it is - in BIOS and Windows).

Any ideas?
I see this problem also existed when upgrading from 2012 to 2013:

http://ridilabs.net/post/2013/12/14/Cannot-Start-Windows-Phone-Emulator-After-Upgrading-to-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx#.UwJf6IX6_bA

Uninstalled update 1, but still no joy. Changed Hyper-V settings in BIOS and WIndows Control Panel, then back again. No change. Vs 2013 is firmly convinced I cant run the emulator.

EDIT:

Downloaded CoreInfo.exe from:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722

copied to C:\
Ran CoreInfo in Command Prompt (Admin) (Windows-Key - X)
coreinfo.exe -v

Result:

Coreinfo v3.21 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topologyCopyright (C) 2008-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
VMX             *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             *       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)

Uninstalled VS2013.
Installed VS2013 (all options selected).
Created new PivotApp1 test project.
No Start button present on toolbar.
Start using drop-down menu
Fails to run as reported above.

Signing in again to MS in VS made no difference (thought it might have been a licencing issue).

Could be a motherboard problem, a chip problem (hardly) or Microsoft problem?, McAfee?
I'll email Bill G. and see what he thinks.

Read 2 articles:
Troubleshooting the Windows Phone 8 Emulator
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

(WP8) Emulator (XDE) Troubleshooting Tips
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68/wp8-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?forum=wptools

Recreated the Hyper-V virtual switch used by the emulator:
"Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch "

Restarted the PC.
No improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Working now.
Seems that I lost the Hyper-V virtual switch. Recreating that, eventually brought up the emulator which, after a few complaints, starting functioning correctly.
Also NO-EXECUTE (XD) in Bios was disabled.
Not sure about the title of this post, but the problem happened after VS 2013 Update 1.

The article mentioned above: WP8) Emulator (XDE) Troubleshooting Tips was essential.

Thanks for being there StackOverflow- it's good to talk.